# mvc.dojox.repeat

Tags: dojo

While using dojox.mvc.Repeat, how do I use the index value ?

If I use #{this.index}, it will provide a reference to the child object at that index location. I don't need a reference to the child object but I want to use the index value.

In the below example, I need to display serial number as the index value.

```
    <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mvc/Repeat" 
         data-dojo-props="exprchar: '#' children: accountsList">
        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Group" data-dojo-props="target: dojox.mvc.at('rel:', '#{this.index}')">  
          <div>Serial No: </div><div data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:', this.index)"></div>
          <div>Account type: </div><div data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:','accountType')"></div>
          <div>Account number: </div><div data-dojo-type="dojox.mvc.Output" data-dojo-props="value: at('rel:','accountNumber')"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```